# Github page, post is not visible

Tags: git, github

I'm a beginner of GitHub page. I wrote some article about user experience. And this article is consist of Korean and English. When I commit my change, But article is invisible.

[image]

In github, the article is visible, but in my domain article is not visible.

[image]

Does anybody know about this problem? Could it be because the language I wrote is in Korean? 
https://github.com/junburg/junburg.github.io
this is my github page link.

Comment: The text is there, just color is white

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined [text color](https://github.com/junburg/junburg.github.io/blob/master/_sass/main.scss#L17) as white but didn't defined background color so your browser uses default background which is also white rendering your text invisible.

Text color and background color must be defined together. Define non-white background color. Or define white background with non-white text color.